# How to move file from one file share to another file share in same azure storage account using Java azure sdk libraries

Tags: azure-java-sdk, azure-storage-files

my application read a file from azure file share. Once file processed, I want to move that file to another file share. How can do this using azure storage file share libraries. Both file shares are in same storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting you need to follow below steps:

Add the `BOM` to your project

Add in the `dependencyManagement` section of your project's POM file. This **does not** result in all dependencies being included in your project.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>{bom_version_to_target}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Add the `libraries` in your project

After adding BOM dependencies you need to add the `azure-storage-blob` , `azure-security-keyvault-secrets` , `azure-identity`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Refer   [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-share/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/file/share/ShareSample.java) for accessing the storage with implementation

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56521677/15997690)  for reading file from one file share and Move it into the same file share different directory